# Building Android msm-3.18 kernel fails on soong-cc-config test on setSdclangVars()

Tags: android, build-error

I am trying to build msm-3.18 kernel for msm8996 (Android 8.0.0).
When trying to build from Android source top directory, it fails on running tests.

Following is the trace

```
FAILED: out/soong/.bootstrap/soong-cc-config/test/test.passed
out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/gotestrunner -p ./build/soong/cc/config -f out/soong/.bootstrap/soong-cc-config/test/test.passed -- \ out/soong/.bootstrap/soong-cc-config/test/test -test.short
panic: read /home/vagrant/android-msm: is a directory

goroutine 1 [running]:
android/soong/cc/config.setSdclangVars()
    /home/vagrant/android-msm/build/soong/cc/config/global.go:197 +0x20d4
android/soong/cc/config.init.2()
    /home/vagrant/android-msm/build/soong/cc/config/global.go:169 +0xcc9
android/soong/cc/config.init()
    /home/vagrant/android-msm/build/soong/cc/config/tidy_test.go:42 +0x3969
main.init()
    /home/vagrant/android-msm/out/soong/.bootstrap/soong-cc-
config/test/test.go:34 +0x4e
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
15:22:17 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
make: *** [run_soong_ui] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/android-msm'
```

I guess it has something to do with $SDCLANG_PATH but I need help

Comment: It seems to have error because `$SDCLANG_AE_CONFIG` inside `android-msm/build/soong/cc/config/global.go` file is blank

Answer (score 3):

You need to register on Qualcomm Developer Network and download their proprietary compiler.

According to instruction on their forum:

1. Download the Qualcomm LLVM Compiler here: https://developer.qualcomm.com/download/sdllvm/snapdragon-llvm-compiler-android-linux64.tar.gz
2. Extract Snapdragon-llvm-3.8.4-toolchain.tar.gz
3. Move toolchains\llvm-Snapdragon_LLVM_for_Android_3.8\prebuilt\linux-x86_64 to prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/sdclang-3.8 within your Android build environment.
4. Add the following lines to your device's BoardConfig:

   ```
   ifneq ($(HOST_OS),darwin)
   SDCLANG := true
   SDCLANG_PATH := prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/sdclang-3.8/bin
   SDCLANG_LTO_DEFS := device/qcom/common/sdllvm-lto-defs.mk
   endif
   ```
5. Compile Android.

Here is instruction from their forum: https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdn-forums/software/snapdragon-llvm-compiler-android/33437